# How to make click event to load event in jquery

Tags: jquery

Here I have jquery which has click it only works when i click on one li but i want to make it work on page load please Help...!

```
//User clicks on a city / gallery;
$fp_galleries.bind('click',function(){
    $fp_galleries.removeClass('current');
    var $gallery = $(this);
    $gallery.addClass('current');
    var gallery_index = $gallery.index();
    if(gallery_idx == gallery_index)
        return;
    gallery_idx = gallery_index;
    //close the gallery and slider if opened
    if($fp_thumbContainer.data('opened')==true){
        $fp_scrollWrapper.fadeOut();
        $fp_thumbContainer.stop().animate({'height':'0px'},200,function(){
            openGallery($gallery);
        });
    }                 
    else
        openGallery($gallery);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the load event to call the click event on the li...

So in the body of the load event... do something like `$('#id_of_li').click()`;

Alternatively... move the body of the click to another function and call that in both the click and the load?